# Query Opportunity Tasks from developer console

Tags: soql, tasks, query

I want id's of tasks related to Opportunity. I tried below in developer console query editor,

```
select id,createdDate from Task where whatid like '006%'
```

But its giving me error,

> Invalid_Query_Filter_Operator

Its giving description as like operator cannot be used for Id field.

How can i query it from query editor then?

Comment: `LIKE` is only for `string` type. Get an idea from http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/is-there-any-way-to-filter-a-soql-or-sosl-query-on-the-id-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
[SELECT Id 
 FROM Task 
 WHERE WhatId IN  (SELECT Id FROM Opportunity)
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use comparison operator `LIKE` with fields of type `ID`:

> The LIKE operator is supported for **string fields** only.

Read more: [Comparison Operators](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)

Instead of `LIKE` use `IN` or `=` opeartors.